# DisplayRectangle for a Panel is too small and matches the ClientRectangle

Tags: c#, scroll, panel

I have a C# Panel that has a horizontal scrollbar so the DisplayRectangle width should be larger than the ClientRectangle, but the DisplayRectangle equals the ClientRectangle.  How to I make the Panel return the correct size for the DisplayRectangle?  I am using it to automatically scroll the panel and take a screenshot of the entire contents of the panel.

```
Rectangle dispRect = panel.DisplayRectangle;
Rectangle cRect = panel.ClientRectangle;
```

Unfortunately dispRect == cRect.

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? What exactly is it that you need to know? A size of a window which is dispayed to the user?

Comment: There is something fishy about this question.  If the DisplayRectangle equals the ClientRectangle then the panel should *not* be showing a scrollbar.  Scrollbars are only visible when DisplayRectangle > ClientRectangle.  Crystal ball says that you actually dropped a HScrollBar on the panel.  Well, don't do that.

Comment: I am using WinForms.  Another thing that is strange is that the HScroll is false and HorizontalScroll.Visible==false.  When I view the form, there is a Horizontal Scrollbar.  Also, the Panel has AutoScroll set to true.  I have tried calling Invalidate() to try to get the right size for the DisplayRectangle, but the size does not change.  I have not dropped an HScrollBar on the panel like Hans said might be true.  I am trying to get the full size of the panel, but at the moment, it only returns the size that is visible.  Is there a way to force the panel to recalculate the DisplayRectangle?

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue, the wrong Panel was being returned from the base class, what I needed was the overridden Panel.